# Increase spacing between physical lines only

Tags: display, whitespace, line-break, wrapping

How can I add spacing where there are linebreaks in the file, but not where a line is word-wrapped? This would be very useful for reading log files with long lines. Here's a mockup of what I'm after:

[image: Log file with large spacing between physical lines]

I found a variable called `line-spacing`, but it controls the spacing between all display lines:

[image: Buffer with large <code>line-spacing</code>]

Comment: Unfortunately, you will be unhappy if you change the default.  Emacs just doesn't do this well.  There is a thread from a year or two ago that discusses this in detail, but I'd need to Google it.  I have gone down that road and ultimately gave up and gone back to default.  I only change the font and size of the letters.